# Битая ссылка в описаниях меток (выделение синтаксиса)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

На страницах описаний меток, которым "назначены" языки программирования, есть вот такое сообщение:

> [image: Язык кода (используется для выделения синтаксиса) lang-cpp]

Ссылка "выделения синтаксиса" ведет на гуглокод, который закрылся. Вероятно, ее надо исправить на вот эту:

https://github.com/google/code-prettify

Answer (score 6):

Спасибо за сообщение!

Я обновил ссылку — результат будет виден в следующем билде (сборка 2016.5.19.3594).